# Send data from android to Amazon s3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do you send data like text or json data from android to amazon s3 bucket ? I want to save the data from my android application to a file on amazon s3

Answer (score 0):

You might think about using AWS SDK https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/.

Answer (score 0):

A nice guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

It shows you how to store and retrieve files with Amazon S3.

Also, there is a sample for S3TransferUtility:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample